# How generate unique order number From Date And Insert to Database?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

```
$order = new Order();
$dt = new DateTime;           
$order->restaurant_id = 1;          
$order->order_no = $dt->format('Y'.'m'.'d'.'0000');
```

'How Make unique order id from date and 0000 number Auto Increment'

Comment: You can use your `Orders` table `primary key` as order_no it is already unique and auto incremented as well.

Comment: The is of the column itself is already unique. If you want to get a bit fancy, you could append to it some sort of an id, maybe the date.

Comment: what is your expected result while generating order number so that i can help For Eg If You Want to refresh the order number every day such as 01012019ORD001 or ORD001 etc

Answer (score 0):

Your `$order->id` should be unique already. I suggest using `$order->order_no = $d->format('Ymd').$order->id` without involving `restaurant_id` that way you will easily know the the part after first 8 characters (`YYYYmmdd`) is the order id to find from database.